# SQL Insert multiple rows with one column always the same and one column different

Tags: sql

Is there a quick way to insert multiple values into one column while the second column has a different value.

Say I have two columns called `Number` and `Colour`.  The `Number` column is always going to be 1 and the `Colour` column changes.

At the moment i'm doing the following...

```
INSERT INTO ColourTable(Number, Colour)

SELECT '1' ,'red'

UNION ALL

SELECT '1' ,'yellow'

UNION ALL

SELECT '1' ,'green'

UNION ALL

SELECT '1' ,'blue'

UNION ALL

SELECT '1' ,'orange'
```

Which is fine if there are just a few inserts to do but the problem is I need to insert about 100 rows with the colour column changing and I was wondering if there was a way to set the number column?

**i think i need to explain myself a little better...

say the colour columns have 40 different colours i need to insert these colours into different rows with the number column saying say 1 to 100 (the number are actually randon codes so incrementing won't work).

So I have to do 40 inserts of the colour rows with the column number =  1
40 inserts with the column number =  2
40 inserts with the column number =  3 and so on to 100

Comment: Where are you getting the values for the colour column? Is that stored in another table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly then you're looking for all combinations of your random code field and colour field.

So for example if you had three colours red, green and blue and 3 random codes 1, 14, 25 then you'd like the following set.

```
1   red
1   green
1   blue
14  red
14  green
14  blue
25  red
25  green
25  blue
```

If this is the case then you could produce a pair of tables, one with the codes, the other with the colours

```
CREATE TABLE #Codes(
    [CodeNumber] int NOT NULL
) 

Insert Into #Codes 
Select 1
Union All
Select 14
Union All
Select 25



CREATE TABLE #Colours(
    [Colour] varchar(50) NOT NULL
) 

Insert Into #Colours 
Select 'red'
Union All
Select 'green'
Union All
Select 'blue'
```

Then use a cross join to return all of the combinations.

```
Select cd.CodeNumber, cl.Colour
From #Codes cd
    Cross Join #Colours cl
```

Answer (score 3):

Put them in separate subselects, and allow a cross join (`,`) to occur:

```
INSERT INTO ColourTable(Number, Colour)
SELECT Num.n,Col.c FROM
 (select '1') Num(n),

 (select 'red' union all
  select 'yellow' union all
  select 'green' union all
  select 'blue' union all
  select 'orange') Col(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO ColourTable(Number, Colour)
SELECT '1' , Col.c FROM
 (select 'red' union all
  select 'yellow' union all
  select 'green' union all
  select 'blue' union all
  select 'orange') Col(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Number` being a `NULL` column, that's pretty straightforward:

```
INSERT INTO ColourTable(Colour) values
('red'), ('yellow'), ('green'), ('blue'), ('orange');

UPDATE ColourTable SET Number = 1 WHERE Number IS NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could set the `DEFAULT` value of the `Number` column to `1` before inserting your rows, and remove it afterwards?

Comment: Sorry the number column will change but only after 40 inserts... so i will have a different number but only change it occassionally while the colour column has to change every time.. i hope that makes sense..

Comment: In this case, you can use a nested loop (in php, for instance): the outer loop for Number values and the inner one for Colour values.

Comment: @barry Hi Barry they do come from another table... but its really the number column that i want to fix and just change once to do multiple columns

Comment: @anna - So the number number column will just increment by one after each 40 inserts?  Are there any duplicate colours?

Comment: @barry please see the edit i made to the original question - the numbers are actually random codes not 1 - 100